# Ethereum sharding minimum committee size of 111 for safety

Tags: security, sharding

I am currently researching the minimum committee size required for Ethereum sharding. According to Vitalik, the minimum number of validators in a committee associated with a malicious committee probability threshold of $2^{-40}$ is 111. This information was presented in one of his talks, which can be found at the following [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190504131341/https://vitalik.ca/files/Ithaca201807_Sharding.pdf).

To determine the required minimum committee size for a given probability threshold, the following mathematical expression can be used:

[image]

However, when I implemented this formula using Python, I found that the threshold was actually 109 instead of 111. While the actual committee size used in Ethereum sharding is 128 (due to base 2 requirements), it is still important to understand the discrepancy between the expected result and my findings.

After further investigation, I discovered that the issue might be due to lower bound specification in the summation. If I use `int(2/3 * committee_size)` with my implementation, I got the threshold of 111. But by using `np.ceil(2/3 * committee_size)` as the lower bound, the required minimum committee size was correctly calculated as 109. And ceiling function is the correct way here since we are looking for a minimum required size.

It's worth noting that the formula uses binomial approximation to hypergeometric distribution. Although the exact modeling should be hypergeometric since this is a sampling without replacement problem, it appears that Vitalik also used the binomial distribution to derive the minimum committee size of 111.